# Image J 16 bit Signed Buffered Image

Tags: java, imagej

So my question is how to get 16 bit bufferedImage from ij.ImagePlus...?
If am trying to get using ShortProcessor it change my signed image to unsigned so i am not getting original image...Thanks in advance can any one provide solution.

[image]

How ImageJ display 16 bit signed image in their viewer..and we only get 8 bit bufferedImage or 16 bit unsigned bufferedImage So how can i get 16 bit signed BufferedImage..?

Comment: How do you get a signed 16-bit image in an `ImagePlus`? To my knowledge, ImageJ only supports _unsigned_ 16-bit images. What does [`ImagePlus#getType()`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/ij/ImagePlus.html#getType%28%29) return?

Comment: @JanEglinger ImageJ supports calibration functions though, which can be used to "simulate" signed 16-bit data. What kamlesh0606 could do is get the unsigned BufferedImage back, then convert it to a signed BufferedImage by looping over the pixels. I'm too busy at the moment to write this up as a proper answer, though...

Comment: yes @ctrueden getting my question properly

Comment: imagePlus.getCalibration().isSigned16Bit() i get true

Comment: Hey I also facing the same problem...can any one give answer..?

Answer (score 1):

ImageJ can represent a signed 16-bit type using a special `Calibration` function. The `isSigned16Bit()` method indicates when that specific calibration function is in use—it is a linear m*x+b calibration where m=1 and b=-32768; this can be [seen in the ImageJ source code](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/v1.48v/src/main/java/ij/measure/Calibration.java#L441).

ImageJ provides a way to obtain a `BufferedImage` from an `ImagePlus` via the `getImage()` method. However, this [always returns an 8-bit `BufferedImage`](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/v1.48v/src/main/java/ij/process/ShortProcessor.java#L130).

So the next approach is to create your own `BufferedImage` with type `DataBuffer.TYPE_SHORT`, which wraps the same `short[]` array that backs the original `ImagePlus` object. Unfortunately, due to ImageJ's internal representation of signed 16-bit data, the values will be off by a constant offset of 32768—e.g., a raw value of -444 will be stored in ImageJ's `short[]` array as 32324. Due to this fact, you must manually adjust all your values before wrapping as a `BufferedImage`.

Here is some example code:

```
import io.scif.gui.AWTImageTools;
...

final ImagePlus imp =
    IJ.openImage("http://imagej.net/images/ct.dcm.zip");

// get pixels array reference
final short[] pix = (short[]) imp.getProcessor().getPixels();
final int w = imp.getWidth();
final int h = imp.getHeight();
final boolean signed = imp.getCalibration().isSigned16Bit();

if (signed) {
    // adjust raw pixel values
    for (int i=0; i<pix.length; i++) {
        pix[i] -= 32768;
    }
}

// convert to BufferedImage
final BufferedImage image = AWTImageTools.makeImage(pix, w, h, signed);
```

For the actual conversion of `short[]` to `BufferedImage`, this code makes use of the [SCIFIO](https://github.com/scifio/scifio) library's [AWTImageTools.makeImage](https://github.com/scifio/scifio/blob/scifio-0.11.0/scifio/src/main/java/io/scif/gui/AWTImageTools.java#L343) utility methods. SCIFIO is included with the [Fiji distribution of ImageJ](http://fiji.sc/). Alternately, it is only a few lines of code which would be easy to copy and paste from the routine in question.

Comment: i am doing same procedure but not getting original image.still not get clear image(in contrast with gray but in real require black)

Comment: Inspect the resultant `BufferedImage`'s pixel values to be certain, but my guess is that the image colors are simply not scaled the way you expect, because it is a 16-bit image. Java does not autoscale `BufferedImage`s when painting them.

Comment: Okay I got it , but any way to show this image in Jdialog.